# How define handler for OOM linux killer in php

Tags: php, linux, memory, error-handling, debian

I have a script which consumes a lot of memory, so Linux Out Of Memory killer kill my script. How i can send email notification, that script was killed by OOM killer ?
P.S. I used `set_error_handler` and `register_shutdown_function` they didn`t help me

**UPDATE:** i think i got it, just do `./test.php || mail.sh` and in the end of `test.php` add `return true;`

Comment: The OOM killer does the equivalent of a `kill -9`. The program does not receive any notification that is it being killed and does not get to do any cleanup.

Comment: @JohnKugelman maybe there is some way to handle it ? i mean not only php, but bash too

Comment: You could trawl syslog, but there's no real guarantee that THAT process won't be shot in the head.  The correct thing to do is a) get more RAM, b) rewrite your script to work with less memory, c) reduce the machines memory over-commit.

Comment: @tink over-commit ? i thought this is for programs that use fork, my script doesn`t fork

Comment: You may (at least as root) disable OOM ... perhaps thru `/proc/self/oom_adj` or some other file under `/proc/`  ...

Comment: Do you know why your script consumes so much memory? Did you consider rewriting it?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch if i disable OOM, will it kill my entire server ?
Yes, i know i should rewrite it, but currently i have not so much time for this script

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch strange thing is that, when i run it from shell manually it didn`t killed, but when cron start it, it fall